# Another application besides ifconfig to change MAC address?

Tags: linux, networking

I have to change my MAC address in order to get an IP lease via DHCP. But almost no installer CDs have ifconfig and dhclient.

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:22:15:C0:27:23
ifconfig eth0 up
dhclient eth0
```

Is there any way to change a MAC address within Debian or Ubuntu installer CDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*iproute2* is the preferred tool:

```
ip link set dev eth0 address 00:22:15:C0:27:23
dhcpcd eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one I have use to change the MAC address is macchanger. It is in Gentoo, Ubuntu, and other common repositories.

Example

```
macchanger --mac 00:11:22:33:44:55 eth0
```

You can even do random MAC addresses with --random